# condition to avoid NPE for nested exceptions when using getCause().getCause()

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, try-catch

I'm working on nested exceptions in java, I wanted to check the type of my custom exception using the condition (eg. `if(t.getCause().getCause() instanceOf MyCustomException)`) but this might throw a potential NPE.

So I'm planned to check for null using below condition

```java
if((t.getCause().getCause() != null) && (t.getCause().getCause() instanceOf MyCustomException)) {
   ..........
}
```

Is it a good approach, Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would not work the way you're planning. Let me explain why:

1. When you use `instanceof` you are already checking if an object is null (e.g. null is not instanceof `myCustomerException`, so it is false)
2. If you are already using `instanceof` it means your problem is not in `t.getCause().getCause()`, but might be with `t.getCause()` or even `t`.

I would suggest you have a method to do the check for you, so you do a clean call. Something like:

```
public boolean isTheNestedException(Throwable t) { // Assuming you are using throwable
    return t != null && t.getCause() != null && t.getCause().getCause() instanceof MyCustomerException; // Assuming your "MyCustomerException" is a custom exception class
}
```

You would use it like:

```
if (isTheNestedException(t) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`instanceOf` does *not* cause `NullPointerException`**.

JLS [15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) says:

> the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* **is not `null`** and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

Now, the *first* `getCause()` can return null, making the *second* call cause NPE, so your code should be:

```
if (t.getCause() != null
 && t.getCause().getCause() instanceOf myCustomeException) {
   ..........
}
```

This presumes that `t` itself cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed code is fragile. If you ever change the nesting, the `if` will break. A better pattern is to write a general purpose search on causal chains:

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
public static <T> T getFirstCause(Throwable ex, Class<T> exClass) {
  for (Throwable cause = ex; cause != null; cause = cause.getCause()) {
    if (exClass.isAssignableFrom(cause)) {
      // Unchecked by Java type system, but verified by the if above.
      return (T) cause;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now you say

```
if (getFirstCause(t, myCustomeException.class) != null) {
   ...
}
```

You can also retrieve the matching instance if needed.

```
myCustomeException customEx = getFirstCause(t, myCustomeException.class);
if (customEx != null) {
   OtherInfo info = customEx.getCustomeExInfo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One if the best ways I've seen is something like

```
Throwable anException = t.getCause();
while(anException != null){
     // Do a thing with with the throwable.
     anException = anException.getCause();
}
```

I didn't test it, but you should get the idea!